Condition for Orthogonal Diagonalizing Matrices and ST
I have a question regarding the diagonalizing matrices in the context of the Spectral Theorem with this formulation:
"May $\phi: V \times V  \to K$ be a non-singular ($V^{\perp}=\{\vec{0}\}) $ scalar product on a K-vector space V, and $f: V \to V$ an endomorphism symmetrical to $\phi$. Then there exists a base B orthonormal with respect to $\phi$ comprised of $f$-eigenvectors"
On my books it's said that this implies that the symmetrical endomorphisms diagonalized by choosing a base $B = \{v_1,...v_n\}$ this way, have their respective symmetrical matrices diagonalized by orthogonal matrices. So if $f$ is symmetrical and $A$ is its matrix in the canonical base, there exists $O$ such that:
\begin{equation}
O^{-1}AO = D \quad\verb|(where D is diagonal)|
\end{equation}
And here comes my problem: the claim that $O$ is orthogonal is made upon the observation that $O$ is written as:
\begin{equation}
O = \left( \begin{array}{c|c|c}
x_1 & ... & x_n \\
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}
($x_i$ has to be the coordinates of $v_i$ with respect to the canonical base $C$ ($x_i = [v_i]_C$) , so that it makes sense to multiply it with $A$ which is the matrix associated with $f$ in the canonical base ( $A =  \it{M}_{C}(f)$ ), but correct me if I'm wrong)
So then, since its coloumns are an orthonormal base:
\begin{equation}
(^\top O O)_{i,j} = (^\top O)_{i} O^{j} = O^{i} O^{j}
\end{equation}
which gives $1$ if $i=j$, and $0$ if $i\neq j$. Thus we conclude that:
\begin{equation}
^\top O O = \mathbb{I}_n 
\end{equation}
Which makes O an orthogonal matrix by definition.
But doesn't this require for $\phi$ to be positive, and not only non singular? It seems like that, in the implication: "orthonormality w.r.t. $\phi$ $\implies$ $^\top O O = \mathbb{I}_n$" we are really assuming that "orthonormality w.r.t. $\phi$ $\implies$ $x_i \cdot x_i = 1$" or in other words that the row-coloumn multiplication which defines matrix composition acts the same way as definite positive scalar product. Which could totally happen if $\phi$ was congruent to the standard euclidean product $\psi$ or in other words definite positive, since if we choose the base $B$ as before$M_C(\psi) = M_B(\phi)$, but I'm not so sure it could happen with an indefinite non singular $\phi$.
Sorry for being somewhat verbose but I could see how you could get lost in unfamiliar notation so I had to explain unclear stuff.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
